# How to enter a directory with the 'cd' command if it has 700 permission and is not owned by me?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, cd-command

I tried to use `sudo cd name_of_dir` but am getting the error message:

```
sudo: cd: command not found
```

Is there any other way to enter a directory owned by another user which has 700 permission?

Comment: please add an `ls -l` of the directory itself.

Comment: And please explain why you keep leaving negative comments against the valid answers here. If you think there is (or should be) a better way, please let us know what it might be.

Comment: `sudo chmod 0755 name_of_dir; do you business; cd ../; sudo chmod 0700 name_of_dir` Seems to be the only answer you'll be happy with.

Comment: @Oli. I was just giving my PERSONAL opinion. If I knew other way of doing that I wouldn't ask it here. I am looking for it. As I see it is almost impossible, BUT there is nothing impossible at all.

Comment: please add an ls -l of the directory itself...

Comment: The answers given here are correct, but you are voting them down and saying they are wrong. Don't just dismiss what is being said because of something else you have seen.

Comment: That is funny... he wants `sudo cd` to work, but he votes down solutions using sudo or su. He says he doesnt want to work as root, but he still wants to access a directly he doesnt own. Sounds like a troll to me...

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`sudo cd` won't work because the `cd` command is built into the shell. So you are saying become root and then run this command. You become root and then the command after sudo is searched for but there is no `cd` command to find.

The method to use is to switch to the user that owns the directory. Permission `700` is meant as "owner can read, write and execute".

So if root owns the directory `sudo -i`, password and then `cd {dir}` is the only correct method. If someone else owns the directory you can still use the 1st method but can also change to that user with `su {username}` and then use `cd` as that user.

Comment: Side question: will root be able to enter a 700 dir even if he is not the owner?

Comment: yes MestreLion,700 will not stop root from enterting. Permissions '000' will stop the user from entering himself (yes, a user can create a dir he himself can not enter...) but still root can enter that one.

Comment: echo is a shell build-in command, why I can run "sudo echo" but not "sudo cd"?

Comment: Sorry, same rules apply to `sudo echo`: you need something like `echo 'deb {text}' | sudo tee --append {file}` to use echo with sudo and to change a  file.

Comment: Why isn't `cd` built into the commands available to `sudo`, though?

Comment: @shoujs [`sudo echo` runs `/bin/echo` instead of the `echo` shell builtin.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960822/why-is-there-a-bin-echo-and-why-would-i-want-to-use-it) ([Rinzwind's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57789/how-to-enter-a-directory-with-the-cd-command-if-it-has-700-permission-and-is-n/57796#comment1241400_57796) is correct, though, as applied to the common situation of `echo` with *output redirection*. `sudo echo text... >> file` isn't what you want since the shell, which is running as you, does the redirection. `echo text... | sudo tee -a file` is a common workaround.)

Comment: Note that `sudo -i` is equivalent to `sudo su -` in that it runs a login shell as the superuser.

Comment: Also, the equivalent of `sudo -i` when the "target user" is not `root` is `sudo -iu username`.

Comment: So this is a limitation (if you can call it that) of the sudo command right? Because it simply looks for executables in the /bin et al. directories? I wonder why there isn't something like suba for running bash internals.

Answer (score 55):

`sudo -i`

to open "root console" and then

`cd /path/to/directory`

(`cd` is a shell builtin command, so it can't be the sudo target)

Answer (score 21):

To open a root directory we may run a root shell, e.g.:

```
sudo su
# cd /root
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to work as a root. NEVER!!! And also experts recommend never login as a root. -1

Comment: Well that's exactly why you don't want permissions to open root's directories, isn't it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong going into root mode. Experts will always recommend going into root when it is -needed-.

Comment: Experts? Never seen expert recommending such stupid thing... Only thing that is not recommended is login to graphical interface as root (and this is also impossible in Ubuntu).

Comment: If you're working with things owned by root, sometimes `sudo su`ing (or another method) is the only practical or even possible method. "Experts" only tell you to not use root as a habit - it's fine when you actually need it. And @Vojtech, nothing's impossible...

Comment: Never do a GUI login as root, or allow root to remotely login (as its the easiest login name to guess for brute-force attacks), but its perfectly fine to use `sudo su -` to root when you need to do plenty of things as root.  Its no more dangerous than typing sudo before each and every command.  You probably should remember to be careful just like with normal `sudo`, and maybe particularly careful to remember to log out; but really there's no extra danger.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: *working* the whole time as root is indeed not recommended. But issuing it for a single (or a few) commands is acceptable. *Specially* if you're trying to enter a directory that you *your user has no permission to*. So you *need* to be either the owner or the root.

Comment: sudo will also log what commands are run through it and who uses them. If you use "sudo su", you don't get this feature. (this isn't saying that "sudo su" is bad. If you need it, use it. And I sometimes use it when I keep pre-pending every command with sudo).

Answer (score 11):

As others pointed out -- it's shell built-in:

```
~ % which cd
cd: shell built-in command
```

So, why don't you sudo the shell itself?

```
~ % sudo $SHELL -c "cd name_of_dir"
```

Comment: +1 for the sudo bash -c idea... and a suggestion: avoid using `which`. Its merely a script, and it wont handle all possibilities (binary, builtin, aliases, etc). Use `type` instead. Much safer, powerful and portable. And `type -p` for the path of an executable.

Comment: Well, depends ;-) `type [ -wfpams ] name ... Equivalent to whence -v.`, `which [ -wpams ] name ... Equivalent to whence -c.` (man zshbuiltins)

Comment: It does *not* depend. `whence`is `zsh`-only... it does **not** work in bash, it is not even installed by default in ubuntu. While `type` is **POSIX**, meaning it will work in *any* modern shell... bash, csh, ksh.. and even zsh.

Comment: Sure, it is and that's why I upvoted your comment just when it appeared, but what I ment was that in zsh actually it's not a script and gives similar results as `type` as both are aliases to the same command.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Well, but thats in `zsh`. In bash, which is the default (and usually only) terminal shell in Ubuntu, `which` is not a builtin... so `type`(or `type -p`) is preferred.

Comment: This do not work, because the `cd` remain in effect only until the end of the script (consisting only of the cd command).

Comment: enzotib: The question was how to enter a directory and my response answers it. Nothing prevents you to use `sudo $SHELL -c 'cd name_of_dir && ls *.txt ; for x in *.txt ; do rm "$x" && echo "just erased $x" ; done'`

Answer (score 7):

You can also elevate yourself to root user by:

```
sudo -s
```

Then you can cd to any directory which doesn't allow normal user in like:

```
cd /root
```

Or

```
cd /var/lib/
```

Then after you're done in there type:

```
exit
```

To logout of the root user privileges.

For elevating yourself as root, you can also combine the two commands by `&&` operator as below, this operator also maintains their execution sequence, if current command executes successfully and only then the next command is allowed to execute:

```
sudo -s && cd /var/lib
```

Or

```
sudo -s && cd /root
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to make `sudo cd directory` work, you can define a `bash` shell function called `sudo` that runs a new root shell when run that way, and just runs the regular `sudo` command otherwise.

As presented in other answers, most users will *not* want to bother doing that, but will instead want to:

1. Run `sudo -s`, or `sudo -i` if you want a login shell (remember that one effect of `sudo -i` is to start you out in root's home directory), or `sudo bash` if you want to force `bash` or be able to pass options to the shell.
2. Run `cd directory` in the new shell.
3. Perform whatever (other) actions need to be taken as root in the new shell.
4. Once done, run `exit` to leave the new shell. It's important not to forget this, because you don't want to perform more actions as root than you intend!

So, if you want to, then you can write a shell function (or a script) that performs the first two of those actions when `sudo` is followed by `cd`, and just runs `sudo` normally otherwise. **Please do not use this as an alternative to learning *why* `sudo cd` does not otherwise succeed**, because if you don't understand what is going on, then you will likely be very confused by being in a new shell (and you may not understand any error messages that occur).

Here's one way to write such a shell function, which also reminds you that you're in a new shell and that you should `exit` out of it when you are finished. (That reminder is likely to be useful for users of *any* skill level, because one is not generally accustomed to being in a new shell when one runs `sudo` without `-s`, `-i`, or the name of an actual shell as an argument.)

```bash
# Make sudo treat "sudo cd [DIRECTORY]" as a special case and start a shell.
sudo() {
    if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && [ "$1" = 'cd' ]; then
        sudo bash -c '
                if cd -- "$2"; then # When cd fails, its own message is enough.
                    printf "%s: Running %s shell in %s\n" "$0" "$USER" "$2" >&2
                    printf "%s: Type \"exit\" once you are done!\n" "$0" >&2
                    exec bash # Replace this bash shell with an interactive one.
                fi
            ' bash _ "$2" # Use $2 as the dir in the intermediate shell, too.
    else
        command sudo "$@"
    fi
}
```

You could put this in your `~/.bashrc`, though this is a weird enough way to use `sudo` that you may only want to enable it occasionally. In that case,  it's better to put it in its own file. If you create a file called `sudo.bash` in your home directory with those contents, then you can make the `sudo` function available--so that it will run instead of the regular `sudo` command--by running `. ~/sudo.bash`. That takes effect in the current shell and its child shells, but not others. For the same reason that files like `.bashrc` are not executable, don't mark `sudo.bash` executable with `chmod`. This is really a library, rather than a standalone shell script. If you *did* run it as a shell script, it would define the function... but only in the shell that ran the script, not for you as the caller. (Of course, you *can* write a script for this, that just doesn't happen to be the approach I've taken here.)

To check and see if `sudo` is currently defined as a shell function, and to see its current definition if it is one, run `type sudo`. To disable (i.e., undefine) the function once it's defined, run `unset -f sudo`. To manually run the regular `sudo` command directly even if the shell function is defined,  run `command sudo`. Note, however, that you don't *have* to do that, because this `sudo` function actually does that itself whenever there are more or fewer than two arguments passed to it or the first argument passed to it is anything but `cd`. **That's why you can still use it in the normal ways people use `sudo`.**

Note also that the shell function shown above does still let you pass other arguments to `sudo`, *but that will prevent it from treating `cd` specially*.  Running `sudo -u user cd directory` in particular is not supported, though you could extend the shell function to support that case. Nor is `sudo -i cd directory`. The shell that it creates is similar to what you get with `sudo -s`. The code does not actually run `sudo -s`, but uses `sudo bash`, so the `-c` option works properly. It actually runs `bash` twice when you pass `cd` and a directory argument to it (and zero times otherwise). When you run `sudo cd directory`, first it forks off a separate bash shell from the one you're running  the `sudo` function in and changes directory. If that succeeds, it *replaces* that bash shell with a new, interactive one that you can use.

Here's an example of how that shell function automatically "does the right thing." Notice that `sudo ls -A /root` behaves normally. Only when I then attempt to `cd` to a directory with `sudo` is a new shell created, and I am reminded explicitly of what is going on.

```
ek@Io:~$ sudo ls -A /root
[sudo] password for ek:
.aptitude      .bashrc  .config  .emacs.d  .nano     .rpmdb
.bash_history  .cache   .dbus    .local    .profile
ek@Io:~$ sudo -k  # invalidates my current timestamp... like I left for a while
ek@Io:~$ sudo cd /root/.local
[sudo] password for ek:
bash: Running root shell in /root/.local
bash: Type "exit" once you are done!
root@Io:/root/.local#
root@Io:/root/.local#
root@Io:/root/.local# exit
exit
ek@Io:~$
```

If you try to `sudo cd` to a directory that you can't change to even as root, then you will just get an error message:

```
ek@Io:~$ sudo cd /nonexistent
[sudo] password for ek:
bash: line 1: cd: /nonexistent: No such file or directory
ek@Io:~$ sudo -k
ek@Io:~$ sudo cd /etc/crontab
[sudo] password for ek:
bash: line 1: cd: /etc/crontab: Not a directory
ek@Io:~$
```

I have used `sudo -k` in between invocations in the above examples to show that it authenticates you as root *before* attempting to change directory. But you don't actually have to run `sudo -k` yourself. Because **the shell function is just a thin wrapper for the real `sudo` command**, caching of your credentials and other common `sudo` behaviors still work normally.

Though it works well and is kind of neat, I admit that shadowing the real `sudo` command with a function of the same name is super weird. Most users will probably just want to perform the steps `sudo -s`, `cd directory` themselves. But in case anybody wants this--and also to demonstrate that it's possible--there it is.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the to `su` or not to `su` debate,  I think it's silly. `su` is against the religion of Ubuntu and it's not something to do carelessly.  It's amazing what an `rm -rf *` can do if you're root.  But, if you're comfortable with the command line interface (CLI) and have system level tasks to do, there's no reason not to use `su`.  I've used several distros where no one even mentioned using `sudo`. It's just a matter of what kind of work you're doing and which method you're most comfortable with. I use both.

Comment: *"In the versions of bash and `sudo` I have with kubuntu lucid, `sudo cd` now works – without any workarounds."* Short of [something like that](https://askubuntu.com/a/985080/22949), which I'm pretty sure has never been in Ubuntu by default, I don't see how. (Also, I've used 10.04; it didn't do that.) It's been years since you posted this, but do you remember the details? Does `sudo cd` still work for you? What's the output of `type -a sudo` in a shell where it works? I understand you may not know--and the second part of your answer remains relevant--but if you do, you can **[edit]** about it.

Comment: @EliahKagan It definitely does not work for me now in 16.10 and I don't remember what I did then. It's against my religion to modify existing base commands, so it's unlikely I did that. In any case, even if it did work, everybody would just call it a bad habit because it wouldn't work generally.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Bauke's solution works when what you're trying to `sudo` is a compound command, such as `cd /some/path && ./executableScript.sh` which may be what you need if `executableScript.sh` needs to be executed from within its directory, and it requires `sudo` both to enter the directory and to run the script (and you want to do this in a non-interactive/session kind of way.

To reiterate, Daniel Bauke's solution is:

```
sudo $SHELL -c "cd /some/path && ./executableScript.sh"
```