# Terminal will not access root folder

Tags: permissions, 18.04, root

I am trying to access the root folder.
I tried `sudo -i cd /root/` and nothing happens. However I was able to access it from nautilus and that works.

Am I missing something? Or is it only possible to access via nautilus?

reference: [I Can't access  the root folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187997/i-cant-access-the-root-folder)

Comment: I was able to use `sudo -i mkdir /root/ca`. But I am not successful at making my way there through the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `sudo -i` opens the root folder automatically. That's what **-i** does.

Second, on Linux you must use forward slash, not backslash to define a path. Use `cd /folder`.

Comment: I apologize, I am working between Windows 10 and Linux. I fixed the typo.

Comment: That makes sense I think I should probably just remove this

Comment: Ok. Just run `sudo -i` again and you'll see that you'll find yourself in the root folder without doing anything else.

Comment: Yes, that works. I was misunderstanding the use of sudo -i.

Answer (score 0):

Use a forward slash in Linux instead of a backslash.

The reason why you cannot use `sudo cd` is explained here: [How to enter a directory with the 'cd' command if it has 700 permission and is not owned by me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57789/how-to-enter-a-directory-with-the-cd-command-if-it-has-700-permission-and-is-n)

What you want to do instead is:

`sudo -i
cd /root/`