# How to access full file system in cubic?

Tags: iso, customization

I recently tried to use the custom Ubuntu ISO image creator, cubic, and was very happy when I was met with a full terminal. But to my dismay, I could not access the full filesystem(Var, Tmp, share, etc.) I tried cd'ing and ls'ing but it was no use. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminal will not access root folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061524/terminal-will-not-access-root-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I had to add a / before the cd, such as cd /tmp/.