# `/root` directory access for superuser

Tags: filesystem, root

I created a new instance
`root@ubuntu-instance:~#`

After creating a superuser named `T1`  I ran:
`root@ubuntu-instance:~# su T1`

Now I end up with the following:
`T1@ubuntu-instance:/root$`

Few questions at this point:
1. How come I have access to `/root` directory even though I am not root user anymore? I thought only root user can have access to the `/root` directory?
2. Or is it that every superuser/user can have its own `/root` directory? Because when I checked the content for the `.profile` file inside the `/root` directory they were different for root user and the superuser
3. Assuming every superuser can access/have its own `/root` directory. How do I do access it? Because I ran, `sudo cd root` but that didn't seem to work.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How come I have access to /root directory even though I am not root user anymore? I thought only root user can have access to the /root
>      directory?

That's just because you happened to be in `/root` when you executed the `su` command. You will find that you cannot re-access `/root` once you leave it:

```
root@t400s:~# pwd
/root
root@t400s:~# su testuser
testuser@t400s:/root$
```

but

```
testuser@t400s:/root$ cd ../
testuser@t400s:/$ cd root
bash: cd: root: Permission denied
```

> 2. Or is it that every superuser/user can have its own /root directory?

No.

> 3. Assuming every superuser can access/have its own /root directory. How do I do access it? Because I ran, sudo cd root but that didn't
>      seem to work.

That's because `cd` is a shell builtin command: `sudo` only works with external executable programs. See for example

- [Why doesn't `sudo cd /var/named` work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291666/why-doesnt-sudo-cd-var-named-work)
- [How to enter a directory with the 'cd' command if it has 700 permission and is not owned by me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57789/how-to-enter-a-directory-with-the-cd-command-if-it-has-700-permission-and-is-n)